# ML.net modelbuilder where to find the test data?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

In the documentation from ML.net is says the following:

> Model Builder splits the training data into a training set and a test
>   set. The training data (80%) is used to train your model and the test
>   data (20%) is held back to evaluate your model. Model Builder uses
>   metrics to measure how good the model is.

Source : [ml.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/automate-training-with-model-builder)

But where can I find the used data to test my model? I cant find it.

Comment: I believe the Model Builder does this internally and doesn't save the test data anywhere. You may be able to use the AutoML package and be able to get access to the test data.

Comment: @Jon Alright,do you have any tips how to do that?

Comment: This should be a good start - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/how-to-use-the-automl-api